# Tracking Error In Stored Procedure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

How to track error in stored procedure in sqlserver? I have stored procedure and it is added to job throush sqlserver agent. I get error in job execution and I get mail but I am not able to track the error down as the error occurs intermittently or once 3-4 days.

Comment: Why don't you check SQL agent job error history.

Comment: @mr_eclair did that but it doesn't show how error occured or where?

Comment: why don't you debug Stored procedure first at SSMS level and then schedule the job. using TRY CATCH or manual debugging process using print to see what data it's processing at each level.

Comment: @mr_eclair the error is intermittent.

Answer (score 1):

If your job encounters an error or raises an error with `RAISERROR`, the job will be marked as failed in the SQL Server Agent job history.  This history is visible by right-clicking a SQL Agent job and choosing View History.

You can add some `BEGIN TRY`/`END TRY` and `BEGIN CATCH`/`END CATCH` statements around your job's code.  This will prevent the job from failing unless you really want it to do so.

Your job can use the `PRINT` statement to output information as it runs.  Some of the output will be visible in the job history.  You could use the `PRINT` to include some trace information as it runs and save error information captured from your `TRY/CATCH` statements.

We have several SQL Agent jobs that run and PRINT information to the job history.  The jobs are careful to TRY/CATCH everything possible.  They only `RAISERROR` if there is a serious problem that the DBA needs to know about.

Our developers occasionally refer to the Agent history to view the trace output.  We use this output to help diagnose problems in our software.